# Download prompt not working in iOS only

Tags: php, ios

```
<?PHP
    $filenames=explode("/",$_GET['q']);
    $filename=end($filenames);
    $url = $_GET['q'];

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize("http://www.example.com/".$url));

    echo file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/".$url);
?>
```

This starts a .jpg download prompt just as I want it to do but only on Windows and Android. On iOS it shows just a little square and nothing happens.

Any suggestions on what is wrong about that?

Comment: Hi, could you include what browser(s) you tested this on?

Comment: this code is incorrect `filesize("http://www.example.com/".$url)` it will only work on local files

Comment: i also think you need double quotes around your filename